How to change the angle or the starting"height" of the new faces created by beveling
I want to bevel a "cube" so it looks like a semicircle, but if I bevel the two edges with clamp overlay on it is too flat, because either the angle, width or startingpoint(?) is too high (Image 1), if I change the width in the bevelmenu nothing happens (probably because clamp overlay is on). If I turn the clamp overlay off, the beveled object looks almost as wanted except that it overlaps and is too low(Image 2). What do I have to do that it looks as wanted(Image 3)?
{Sorry if that`s a very basic question/problem and a potential sorry if the english is bad(not native speaker)}[]
[]
[]

To make sure it becomes a semi-circle, the width has to be twice the height and the scale has to be applied(!), which is the main reason for uneven beveling. Make sure to apply it in Object Mode with Ctrl+A > Apply > Scale.

It is always a matter of applying the scale of the mesh you want to bevel because otherwise your bevelled edges will look as yours.
Another thing you could do is to select the middle edge and with proportional editing expanding it until acquires shape you want. Obviously for this you will need to align it with one of the axis to make it accurate.
You could also extrude a cylinder, remove the flat area and join meshes together to merge vertices later.
Good luck! Don’t forget to apply transforms :P
